# React Native iOS build install through wire but not with ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm using Xcode 10.1 and iOS 12.1
Also I'm using Firebase Firestore on my Project.

I have done all  provisiong profile procedure and app running fine when install on device through wire from xcode but when I make archive and build successfully and install ipa file through https://www.diawi.com/ it's install 70% and then icon get black and stop installing. Please someone guide me. Am I doing anything wrong?

Here is my pods

```
platform :ios, '12.1'

target 'ebikes' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ebikes

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

  # [OPTIONAL PODS] - comment out pods for firebase products you won't be using.
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.6'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.1'


  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTVibration',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork'
    ]

  pod 'yoga', path: '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'

  pod 'RNI18n', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-i18n'



end
```

Comment: Have you changed your scheme to release before archiving?

Comment: What kind of provisioning profile are you using for building the `ipa` that you are putting on diawi.com? Is it `ad-hoc`, `app-store` or `enterprise`?

Comment: Yes I have changed scheme to release and its ad-hoc